# Finding the combination of creating 2 pairs

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

We have 5 men and 3 women. We are to create 2 pairs of man/female ( the order of pairs does not matter )

We can create one pair using basic formula for combinations using

$\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1}=15$

But how can we create two pairs?

i tried using

$\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1} + \binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}$
Since first pair has one man and one woman ,in the second pair we choose from one less man and woman.
This equals 23 but that answer is incorrect.

// edit

i realised i cannot add it together and edited my formula into

$\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}$ which is 120 but still incorrect

Comment: See barak manos's answer for the correct expression, but regarding the wrong answers you gave: the first, ${5\choose 1}{3\choose 1}+{4\choose 1}{2\choose 1}$ doesn't work, as you said, because of the addition- it instead counts the number of pairs with the first $5$ and $3$ and the number of pairs with the remaining $4$ and $2$, but it doesn't count how to put those pairs together, which is multiplication. However, ${5\choose 1}{3\choose 1}{4\choose 1}{2\choose 1}$ puts an order on the pairs, which is wrong. You can then divide that by $2$ (unordering the pairs), to get $60$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the following:

- Number of ways to choose $2$ out of $5$ men: $\binom52=10$
- Number of ways to choose $2$ out of $3$ women: $\binom32=3$
- Number of ways to split $2$ men and $2$ women into $2$ couples: $2$

The answer is $10\cdot3\cdot2=60$.

Answer (score 0):

It is like arranging a mixed doubles tennis match.

The $4$ individuals can be selected in $\binom52\binom32 = 30$ ways

**You** can be paired with any one from the two of opposite gender,

thus $30\cdot\binom21 = 60$ ways